# 特定のリンクに対するjavascriptの検索と無効化について

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

stylish,greasemonkyでニコニコ動画のページ改善を行っています。
例えば、この動画(http://www.nicovideo.jp/watch/sm8628149) ですと、
動画ページの「メニューを開く」ボタンを押すと、幾つかのボタンが現れますが、この中でツイッター投稿ボタン(.twitterButton)だけ右クリックでポップアップが出現するようになっています。
これを止めたいのですが、どう調べれば良いか分かりません。
要素を検証した所、ポップアップが出ない他のボタンと同じようなjsが書かれていて、なぜポップアップが出るか分かりません。
仕様ブラウザはfirefoxです。

知りたいことは
1.具体的にどの部分がポップアップを出現させているのか、またその調べ方
2.それを消すにはどうすればよいか
です。直接的な回答でなくとも、何を調べればよいかを教えていただけるとありがたいです。

Comment: @unarist　回答ありがとうございます！提案頂いたコードで無事にポップアップを抑制出来ました。

Comment: コメント欄は回答の下にもあるので、回答に対してコメントしたい場合はそちらを使うとよいです。それと、質問が解決したときは回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックすると、解決済みというマークになります。

Comment: 回答の下のコメント欄にはありがとうございますなどを書かないようにと書いてあったため躊躇してしまいました。ご丁寧にルールまで教えていただきありがとうございます！解決済みに設定しました。

Comment: 「ありがとうございますなどを書かないように」というのはどこのコメント欄でも同じです（参考 http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers）が、それより、質問のコメント欄は質問内容についてコメントや不明点を指摘する場所ということの方が大きいです。回答者に通知も送ることもできません。

Comment: これからは回答に対してはその下のコメントをつかいます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 何が起きているか

- そのTwitterボタンは `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?...` へのリンクにすぎないのですが、Twitterのwidget.jsの機能でポップアップとして表示されるようになっています。
- widget.jsは document の click イベントを拾って、これを処理しています。
- 多くのブラウザは右クリックでは click イベントが発生しないのですが、**Firefox に限っては** document 要素にだけ click イベントが発生します。
  http://d.hatena.ne.jp/rikuba/20101221/1292875401
- MouseEvent には押されたボタンを表す button プロパティがありますが、widget.jsはこれを見ていません

というわけで、widget.jsによるリンクのポップアップ化機能を使っているサイトは基本的に、Firefoxでこの問題が起きるはずです。実際これだけのコードで再現できます。

```html
<script src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://example.com" target="_blank">ツイート</a>
```

他のブラウザの挙動などを考えるとFirefoxが周りに合わせるべきのような気はしますが、2002年に登録されたバグ報告は音沙汰ないですねえ。。。

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184051

### 抑制する方法

幸い、widget.jsはバブリングフェーズでイベントを捕えています。なのでキャプチャフェーズで `e.stopPropagation()` を呼び出し、その先への伝播を止めることができます。

```
document.addEventListener('click', e => e.button === 2 && e.stopPropagation(), true)
```

### 今回の調べ方など

ポップアップが表示されるということは `window.open()` を呼び出しているということですから、`window.open = () => {console.trace();debugger}` といった感じに調査コードを仕込むことができます。widget.jsはminifyされていたので、minify解除したものにデバッグプロキシで差し替えたりもしました。
<sub>※console.traceも入れているのは、非同期呼び出しの登録コードまでトレースするためです。</sub>

また、ブレークした状態でコールスタックをさかのぼるとイベントハンドラがあり、ローカル変数にEventオブジェクトを見つけました。このオブジェクトのプロパティから

- currentTarget (addEventListener先): document
- type (Event種別): click
- button (押されたボタン): 2 (右ボタン)

等もわかりますね。